# How to define a screw as a decoration in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to define a decorator that draws a screw between the two connected points. Until now this is what I have:

```
\documentclass{article}   
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}

\pgfdeclaredecoration{screw}{initial}
    {
    \state{initial}[width=1.5pt,next state=midd]
        {
        % First line
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0.0pt}{3.0pt}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{1.5pt}{1.5pt}}
        % Second line
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0.0pt}{0.0pt}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0.0pt}{-3.0pt}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{1.5pt}{-1.5pt}}
        }
    \state{midd}[width=3.2pt]
        {
        % First line
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{1.5pt}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0.6pt}{2.0pt}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{1.6pt}{1.5pt}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{2.6pt}{1.0pt}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{3.2pt}{1.5pt}}
        % Second line
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{-1.5pt}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0.6pt}{-2.0pt}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{1.6pt}{-1.5pt}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{2.6pt}{-1.0pt}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{3.2pt}{-1.5pt}}
        }
    \state{final}
        {
        %\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{1.5pt}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{2.0pt}{0pt}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{-1.5pt}}
        }
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
    \draw[decorate,decoration=screw] (0,100pt) -- (0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I would like to be able to change the amplitude and the spacing of the threads, too. How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  I would suggest looking at the definition of the `coil` decoration and seeing how it introduces parameters.

Comment: Thanks! Could you tell me in which file it is defined, please? ... I can't find it.

Comment: it's in the manual

Comment: I once drew a screw using a pic for one thread, repeating as needed.

Comment: But if you use a picture, you cannot control parameters such as the separation of threads.

Comment: I think @JohnKormylo was suggesting a `pic` - not a picture. Is your question solved? If so, it would be better to present your solution as an answer, rather than incorporating it into the question. The question space is best reserved for ... , well, for questions, really ;).

Comment: @cfr Yes, my question is solved. I didn't know that I could answer my own question :P I'll do it then.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So, I could solve my problem with this code:

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
% New decoration for screws
\tikzset{/pgf/decoration/.cd,
    head width/.initial=6pt,
    head length/.initial=1.5pt,
    thread separation/.initial=1.0pt,
    thread amplitude/.initial=0.5pt,
    screw radius/.initial=1.2pt,
}
% definition of the decoration
\pgfdeclaredecoration{screw}{initial}
{
  \state{initial}[width=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/head length},%
                  next state=midd]
  {
    \def\headlength{%
      \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/head length}%
    }
    \def\headwidth{%
      \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/head width}%
    }
    \def\screwradius{%
      \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/screw radius}%
    }
    % First line
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0.0pt}{\headwidth/2}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\headlength}{\screwradius}}
    % Second line
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0.0pt}{0.0pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0.0pt}{-\headwidth/2}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\headlength}{-\screwradius}}
  }
  \state{midd}[width=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/thread separation}*2]
  {
    \def\threadseparation{%
      \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/thread separation}%
    }
    \def\threadamplitude{%
      \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/thread amplitude}%
    }
    \def\screwradius{%
      \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/screw radius}%
    }
    % First line
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{\screwradius}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0.5*\threadseparation}{\screwradius+\threadamplitude}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{1.0*\threadseparation}{\screwradius}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{1.5*\threadseparation}{\screwradius-\threadamplitude}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{2.0*\threadseparation}{\screwradius}}
    % Second line
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{-\screwradius}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0.5*\threadseparation}{-\screwradius-\threadamplitude}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{1.0*\threadseparation}{-\screwradius}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{1.5*\threadseparation}{-\screwradius+\threadamplitude}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{2.0*\threadseparation}{-\screwradius}}
    % Thread
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0.5*\threadseparation}{\screwradius+\threadamplitude}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{1.5*\threadseparation}{-\screwradius+\threadamplitude}}
  }
  \state{final}
  {
    \def\screwradius{%
      \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/screw radius}%
    }
    %\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{\screwradius}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{2.0pt}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{-\screwradius}}
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
  \node (a) at (0pt,50pt) {};
  \node (b) at (0pt,0pt) {};
  \draw[decorate, decoration={screw}] (a) -- (b);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
  \node (c) at (0pt,50pt) {};
  \draw[decorate, decoration={screw, thread separation=0.5pt}] (c) arc(-180:-90:40pt);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
  \node (d) at (0pt,0pt) {};
  \node (e) at (70pt,0pt) {};
  \draw[decorate, decoration={screw, screw radius=5pt, head width=15pt, head length=3pt}] (a) -- (b);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]